# Loading external jQuery files with $

Tags: jquery

I have searched all over the internet for an answer, please I need someone to help me. I am writing a plugin and I am loading an external Javascript/jQuery file that uses the $ as usual.

We all know that WordPress jQuery file is in no conflict mode. Here are the options I found but none of them seems to work in my case:

1.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

});
```

Problem: This only applies to custom script you write. What if you are loading external file

2. Add this before `wp_head()`

   `var $ = jQuery.noConflict();`

Problem: I am writing a plugin, not theme. I am not in control of that

3. Add this before the external file

   `var $ = jQuery;`
   Problem: You may not be able to do this

Comment: Is there any scope to fix the external file? It would be easy to get them to wrap it in a self-executing function that had argument $ that was passed in jQuery, which would solve this with appropriate scope (at least depending on how that script exports functions)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using follow snippet

```
// Add scripts to wp_head()
function child_theme_head_script() { ?>
    <!-- Your HTML/JavaScript goes here -->
<?php }
add_action( 'wp_head', 'child_theme_head_script' );
```